# Почему-то медленно посылаются запросы

Tags: php, javascript, sql, производительность

Сами страницы на сайте грузятся быстро, с базой тоже всё в порядке, проверял. Да и запросы самые типичные, что могут быть. Не пойму в чём дело, может в js коде?

Вот ссылка на сайт - http://montytool.ru/

Попробуйте к примеру нажать кнопку Войти, потом ещё раз и вы увидите, что долго как-то лоадер идёт...

А с кнопкой Создать аккаунт всё хорошо, грузит быстро окно. Вот и возникает мысль, что в js коде какие-то проблемы. И такая беда везде на сайте. Но страницы почему-то грузятся быстро.

**Кстати, на денвере всё летает. А на хостинге нет.**

Вот php функция входа(индекс по **ulogin** стоит):

```
 public function login($params) {
  global $db;
  $login = $db->escape(trim($params['login']));
  $password = $db->escape(trim(md5(md5($params['password']))));

  $query = $db->query("SELECT `uid`, `upassword`, `uhash` FROM `users` WHERE `ulogin` = '$login'");
  $data = $db->fetch($query);

  $user_id = $data['uid'];
  $hash = $data['uhash'];

  if($db->error()) {
   $json = array('error_title' => 'Ошибка', 'error_text' => 'Не удалось соединиться с сервером. Попробуйте позже.', 'error_size' => 400);
  } elseif($password == $data['upassword']) {
   user::auth_cookies($user_id, $hash);
   $json = array('response' => 1);
  } else {
   $json = array('error_title' => 'Ошибка', 
    'error_text' => '
    Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность написания <b>логина</b> и <b>пароля</b>. 
    <div class="helper">
     <div class="ul">
      <div class="li"></div>
      <div class="text">Возможно, нажата клавиша CAPS-lock?</div>
      <br />
      <div class="li"></div>
      <div class="text">Может быть, у Вас включена неправильная <b>раскладка</b>? (русская или английская)</div>
      <br />
      <div class="li"></div>
      <div class="text">Попробуйте набрать свой пароль в текстовом редакторе и <b>скопировать</b> в графу «Пароль»</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="end">
     Если Вы всё внимательно проверили, но войти всё равно не удается, Вы можете <a href="#"><b>нажать сюда</b></a>.
    </div>
    ', 'error_size' => 560
   );
  }

  return json_encode($json);
 }
```

Comment: @Чад, и как теперь быть? Кстати я заметил, что именно с post запросами такое дело, а с get например всё быстро.

Comment: Сменить хостинг? Изменить тарифный план? Смириться?

Comment: @Чад, Вы были правы насчёт защиты. Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, помечу как "верный". Спросил у хостинга, получил ответ: Здравствуйте, это защита от брутфорса. 

Сколько POST запросов в минуту и с 1 IP вам нужно обрабатывать?
Запросы делаются браузером или скриптами/программами/ботами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется тут дело в сервере, что то типа защиты от ддос атаки. если вы сделаете повторный запрос секунд через 10 - он пройдёт очень быстро. Решать такие проблемы надо общением с провайдером.

Comment: @Чад, готово, спасибо большое, они мне убрали эти защиты свои ;)